# Why is my application executing top to bottom

Tags: f#

I thought I understood F# code execution but clearly I'm missing something. When I run the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env fsharpi

let a =
    System.Console.WriteLine("Function A")

let b =
    System.Console.WriteLine("Function B")

let c =
    System.Console.WriteLine("Function C")

c
b
a
```

I get the output:

```
Function A
Function B
Function C
```

So for some reason it's executing the functions as it reads them in instead of the function calls which are in reverse order.

Why is this?

Comment: Those aren't functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what this line means:

```
let a =
    System.Console.WriteLine("Function A")
```

It assigns **the result of `System.Console.WriteLine("Function A")` to `a`**. If you run it you'll see `a` is typed as `unit`:

```
val a : unit = ()
```

And at that time "Function A" was already written to console.

What you probably want is `a` to be a function and not a value:

```
let a() =
    System.Console.WriteLine("Function A")
```

It can be called using `a()`. If you put that all together:

```
let a() =
    System.Console.WriteLine("Function A")

let b() =
    System.Console.WriteLine("Function B")

let c() =
    System.Console.WriteLine("Function C")

c()
b()
a()
```

you'll get what you expect:

```
Function C
Function B
Function A
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. Thank you for clarifying. That makes much more sense.